# Sprite color not changing in Swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift

My sprite image is black, I want to change this color to whatever I want.
The code I'm using:

```
var sprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "layer1-0\(random(1..<4))")
            ceilingPieces.append(sprite)


            sprite.setScale(0.5)

            sprite.position = CGPointMake(900, 335)

            sprite.color = UIColor.purpleColor()

            sprite.colorBlendFactor = 1.0

            self.addChild(sprite)
```

The image stays black, but I want it to be purple.
Thanks!
Toby.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A black tile image isn't going to be able to tint. You're working with filters here so it doesn't matter what you put over it, it's still going to look black. Get a white or mostly white image and you'll see that it will work as expected. Again, tint color is multiplied by the original color to get to the end result.

If you were instead working with

```
var sprite = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.blackColor(), size: CGSizeMake(100, 100))
```

you could then change the color but it would be a blend, it would simply be changing the color with

```
sprite.color = UIColor.purpleColor()
```